# How to get an URL for playing full song rather than just preview using Spotify API?

Tags: spotify

Currently, I am able to play only the Preview version of the song using the song's preview_url from the response object. Is there any way to fetch the entire song?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play full spotify track inside my own website using spotify web api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705253/play-full-spotify-track-inside-my-own-website-using-spotify-web-api)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Playback of full tracks is not supported in the Web API.

If you are making a mobile app, playback is offered through the mobile SDKs, but there is no full playback for web at this time.

Mobile SDKs can be found here:
https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/
https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/