# Spotify API full song play

Tags: node.js, angular, spotify

I am trying to make a music streaming web-app using spotify's API. But after many research I am not able to find a way by which we can stream a song from spotify by just clicking the play button from our web-app. I think spotify just offers song's meta data and listing that's it, not the song to play in other web-app. Let me know if I am wrong because I am really looking forward to make this project with the help of Angular.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play full spotify track inside my own website using spotify web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705253/play-full-spotify-track-inside-my-own-website-using-spotify-web-api)

Comment: See: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/quick-start/ Be mindful about spotify terms. "This SDK must not be used in commercial projects without Spotify's prior written approval"